# Start a ClickOnce Application From a Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, clickonce

OK,

So I'm trying to figure out a way to launch a ClickOnce application from a Windows Service. I wanted to do it via the "Local System" (So no log in information prompts were done) account without the "Interact with desktop" option checked (since MS has been trying to get rid of that feature for a while).

I knew that I could launch a application to the desktop without that checked. So I dug a CreateProcessAsUserWrapper from the TechNet Blog. The wrapper can be found here http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSCreateProcessAsUserFromSe-b682134e/file/50832/8/Interactive%20Windows%20Service%20(CSCreateProcessAsUserFromService).zip

I then created the services application and a small exe with a copy of the .appref-ms of the ClickOnce applicaiton. The server then looks every 10 minutes to see if the ClickOnce app is running. If not it fires off the small exe with the CreateProcessAsUserWrapper which then in turn .appref-ms

Up to this point everything is running smoothly. The problem I've run into is that with the ClickOnce App starts up. It asks if it wants to install, despite being installed.

This is the code starting up the ClickOnce app:

```
string startupPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
startupPath = Path.Combine(startupPath, "app.appref-ms");
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "\"" + startupPath + "\"";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

I don't know if there is anything i do to prevent it from asking to install. I have even tired switching the server over to run under the user account, but then I get errors Querying the User Token for when trying to interact with the desktop.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to run an app with a UI from a service?  There's just so much potential for problem...  Remember clickonce apps are installed *per user* so just because "it's installed" doesn't mean it's installed for the user context of the service.

Comment: Our staff have a habit of closing a program by mistake that should always be running.

Comment: Sounds more like *that* app should be a service, or run behind a task bar icon or something...

Comment: I just switched it to a console app with a notify icon and without the CreateProcessAsUserWrapper. Odlly it was still prompting for install. I think I may have to do away with the Clickonce aspect of the primary app and do a self updater.